# Redirecionamento com Timer MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

Estou com um probleminha que estou quebrando a cabeça pra resolver.

Estou construindo um site MVC e gostaria de fazer uma página de inauguração com Timer rolando como esta imagem:

[image: Timer de inalguração]

Até aí, beleza. O problema é que eu quero que quando acabe esse contador ele redirecione para a pagina inicial. Segue o código da View:

```
<table class="countdownContainer">
    <tr class="info">
        <td colspan="4">Contagem Regressiva</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="info">
        <td id="days">120</td>
        <td id="hours">4</td>
        <td id="minutes">12</td>
        <td id="seconds">22</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Dias</td>
        <td>Horas</td>
        <td>Minutos</td>
        <td>Segundos</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">

            function countdown(){
                var now = new Date();
                var eventDate = new Date(2016, 10, 01);

                var currentTiime = now.getTime();
                var eventTime = eventDate.getTime();

                var remTime = eventTime - currentTiime;

                var s = Math.floor(remTime / 1000);
                var m = Math.floor(s / 60);
                var h = Math.floor(m / 60);
                var d = Math.floor(h / 24);

                h %= 24;
                m %= 60;
                s %= 60;

                h = (h < 10) ? "0" + h : h;
                m = (m < 10) ? "0" + m : m;
                s = (s < 10) ? "0" + s : s;

                document.getElementById("days").textContent = d;
                document.getElementById("days").innerText = d;

                document.getElementById("hours").textContent = h;
                document.getElementById("minutes").textContent = m;
                document.getElementById("seconds").textContent = s;

                setTimeout(countdown, 1000);
            }

            countdown();

</script>
    <img src="~/Images/Sem Título-1.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Em Breve!"/>
```

Gostaria que quando acabasse o contador e atingisse a data de inauguração 01/10/2016, a pagina fosse redirecionada para a Home.

Answer (score 4):

Não tem muito segredo:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        function countdown(){
            var now = new Date();
            var eventDate = new Date(2016, 10, 01);

            if (now > eventDate)
                window.location.replace("http://sitefinal");

            ...
```